# Search multi-dimensional array before pushing to array, no duplicate data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I'm trying to build 'wishlist' functionality. When you click a button, it saves the name and link for the particular 'property' in an array in local storage. I will then output this on the page for the user.

So far it works, my only problem is that it will always insert the property name and link, even if it's already present in the array. I need to create a check, to see if it's already there, and only push it if it can't be found.

Here's a JSFiddle that works. Click the "save" buttons and check localStorage and you will see that the data is added. But click the same button again and you'll see it's added, again.

https://jsfiddle.net/g9kkx3fh/3/

Here's the basic code. It grabs the property name and link from the closest clicked button, it pulls data back from the array in localStorage, then uses `.push` to add the new data, then re-stringifys it and adds it back to localStorage.

```
var name = $(this).closest('.text-long').find('.intro-text h4').text();
var permalink = $(this).closest('.text-long').find('.button-slot a').attr('href');
var property = [name, permalink]; // create an array of the name + permalink
var wishlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist")); // get the wishlist from storage
wishlist.push(property); // append the new array into the wishlist from storage
localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(wishlist)); // put the wishlist back in storage
```

I knew I needed to iterate over the array, being multi-dimensional, and look for the same `name` var. So I started with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wishlist.length; i++) {
    var isPresent = ($.inArray(name, wishlist[i]));
}
if (isPresent == -1){
    wishlist.push(property);
    localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(property));
}
```

Here's the problem with this. If the localStorage var `wishlist` is empty, then its `length` is 0. Therefore the `for` loop never works, because `i < wishlist.length` is never true, because `wishlist` is always 0.

So how do I fix this? I'm never able to add anything to the array, because I can never get the value of `isPresent`, because my `for` loop never works.

Here's a JSFiddle for the broken code, but with the for loop and if statement added:

https://jsfiddle.net/bdxa0sgz/1/

I've also tried the following:

```
if (isPresent == -1 || wishlist.length == 0){
...
}
```

So that if the wishlist is empty, it'll still run. However this seems to jumble together the `name` data and overwrite the array. I'm very confused.

https://jsfiddle.net/bdxa0sgz/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use Map (key, value) pair to store your properties so that you can check using

```
myMap.get(key)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get

Here, have a look at this detailed article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

For your example,

```
var myMap = new Map();
$('body').on('click', '.icon.heart button', function(e) {
    var name = $(this).closest('.text-long').find('.intro-text h4').text();
    var permalink = $(this).closest('.text-long').find('.button-slot a').attr('href');
    var property = [name, permalink];
    console.log(property);
    if (myMap.get(name) === null) {
        var wishlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist"));
        console.log('Wishlist from localStorage = ' + wishlist);
        wishlist.push(property);
        console.log(wishlist);
        localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(wishlist));
        myMap.set(name, permalink);
    }
});
```

You can also iterate through the map to get all the properties like this:

```
var mapIter = myMap[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(mapIter.next().value);
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Can you please show how that works with my code example?

Comment: OK, can you please show how this works with my code? I've added it to a new JSFiddle. I don't get anything in the localStorage array anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmygbbvz/1/

Comment: in your code, you're not adding anything in your wishlist so you're not getting anything in localStorage. I tried running your code and it seems it reads null in name and permalink var after clicking on save button.

Comment: The code here works OK: https://jsfiddle.net/g9kkx3fh/3/ - I just need advice on how to add your map functionality to this code.

Comment: i have modified the code. Checking the value in map (present or not) will determine whether to not push the property in wishlist or to do it respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Before you push the `property` array to the `wishlist` array you have to check if `wishlist` contains it right. So you might simply do it like this. Let's invent a generic `Array.prototype.compare()` method. However since this is going to be a generic method it also takes care of the possibility of array elements being objects. So we have an `Object.prototype.compare()` too (in this case we don't need it but it's good to know) So here is the code;

```js
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};
Array.prototype.compare = function(a){
  return this.every((e,i) => typeof a[i] === "object" ? a[i].compare(e) : a[i] === e);
};
var button1 = ["29 Melton Road32 York Road","http://localhost:8888/test-properties/properties/29-melton-road/"],
    button2 = ["32 York Road","http://localhost:8888/test-properties/properties/32-york-road/"],
   wishlist = [],
    push2wl = btn => wishlist.some(a => a.compare(btn)) ? wishlist : wishlist.concat([btn]); // if exists return wishlist untouched
wishlist = push2wl(button1); 
wishlist = push2wl(button2); 
wishlist = push2wl(button1); // this won't get inserted
wishlist = push2wl(button2); // this won't get inserted

console.log(wishlist);
```

I use arrow functions but you may replace them with their conventional counterparts if you want to see your code work on Safari 9 or IE.

Comment: Can you show an example of this working with my code, as in my JSFiddle?  https://jsfiddle.net/g9kkx3fh/3/

Comment: @user1486133 OK here you go : https://jsfiddle.net/g9kkx3fh/6/ It's working perfectly as you wanted. I just added `Array.prototype.compare()` and changed the `wishlist.push(property);` line to `wishlist.some(a => a.compare(property)) || wishlist.push(property);`

Comment: @user1486133 One more thing. You look like a Mac user... If so the above snippet probably won't work with Safari since it is still not OK with arrow functions. Please run it with Chrome or replace the arrows with it's conventional counterparts. Like `Array.prototype.compare = function(a) {
  return this.every(function (e, i) {return a[i] === e})};` and `wishlist.some(function (a){ return a.compare(property)})`